# Swedish characters (åäö) not working on webserver but works on local computer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, utf-8, cultureinfo

As the headline says I have some strange problem of getting the special characters to work on the webserver but they show properly when I run the homepage from my local computer.

Using visual studio express 2012 for web.
.NET framework is verison 4.5.51209.

In the aspx.vb file I change the Culture using.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("sv-SE")
```

And in the aspx file I have this code telling it should use UTF-8.

> Page Language="VB" Culture="sv-SE" AutoEventWireup="false"
>   CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default"  UICulture="SE"

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```

[image: Running from local computer]

[image: Running from webserver]

Can someone help me and tell me what I'm missing?

The regional setting on the local computer is: Swedish (windows 7)
On webserver it's  also Swedish (windows server 2008 R2)

Cheers

Comment: It seems you're using different character encodings. Try using Unicode UTF-8 on both sides.

Comment: @DerGolem 
I'm connecting to a oracle database and connect the result to a gridview.

Also been putting in the webconfig file 
    <globalization
    fileEncoding="utf-8"
    requestEncoding="utf-8"
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="sv-SE"
    uiCulture="sv-SE"
    /> 
So I don't get what you mean on both sides?

Comment: Both sides: local and remote (server). Windows has the funny habit of using by default a naive "codepage", which 99 times out of 100 causes problems.

Comment: @DerGolem
Silly question where should I then change that on the server?
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Check the database settings as well as the server config. Also check the application settings. More than this I can't figure out.

Comment: To avoid any conversion problems, use Unicode fields in the database (nvarchar/nchar) and *don't* try to force any specific encoding for the page. .NET uses Unicode internally and encodes web page responses as UTF8 by default. Encoding problems occur when ASCII data is used with different codepages eg between database and server, server and header encoding etc. In your case, forcing `sv-SE` is the cause of the problem. I'll bet Oracle uses AMERICAN_AMERICA and the field is `varchar`